# Face and Normal Constraint When Moving Vertex/Edge (Like 3DS Max)

Tags: modeling

so in Blender we have edge/vertex slide which does moving edge/vertex constraints to nearest edge or nearest vertex. but as far as i know, we don't have Face and Normal based constraint.
How achieve this kind of constraint in Blender?

Please take a look at this video at 22:58

[Arrimus Topology Tutorial Time Stamp = 22:58](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFL24N8G8ow)

-As for face constraint, i found complicated workaround which uses shrinkwrap modifier, then duplicate the object and make it as target, which is not the best solution.

thank you guys!

Comment: Try swtiching Transform Orientation to Normal (Alt+Space menu), then with vertex selected move it and constrain only Z normal axis by pressing Shift+Z and then again Shift+Z.

Comment: i guess the solution that you mentioned is not the same with what 3ds max do in video that i gave above.

Comment: I've no idea. If you see the differences in result then show examples of what happens and what you expect to happen. Preferably screenshots or gifs if possible

Comment: Addon Machin3 Tools have Surface Slide that can do exactly this. Also it can do scale constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You move the vertex and it moves the face. It doesnt make sense for blender because you're trying to snap to the face which you're currently editing. You may try any workaround you like from this list:

- use Normal transform orientation and press Shift+Z twice during transform. The most unprecise method, because the vertex's normal is a single directinon, when faces connected to that vertex have multiple normal directions. So it actually doesnt use all faces normals but summary direction of them all.
- duplicate an object to use it as a reference for shrinkwrap modifier.
- duplicate any vertex and use face snapping. Move your topology to that vertex, using it as a guide point.

3ds max doesnt have that problem