# Constrain vertex to its face

Tags: constraints, snapping, transform-orientation

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

I want to use the scale tool to move the selected vertices closer to each other, but I want to do so without affecting the shape of the face. The normals of the two face may not be the same either (they might point in reflected directions, i.e. one measures 30 degrees and the other -30 degrees).

In 3ds max you can enable face constraints, and then all vertex movements happen only along a face. Is there such a thing in Blender? Or is there another way to achieve this.

Comment: If you move a vertex, you _are_ changing at least a face shape. Each of those vertices is shared by three faces, so moving it you will change the shape of three faces...

Comment: I don't know max, but think blender has no tools capable to do that. There could be a way, imho, to achieve that but it could be quite difficult to explain with words only so, if you will share your model (use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then edit your post adding the provided link), we could try use that to achieve a solution specific to your model.

Comment: about max face constraint, I found this https://youtu.be/UFL24N8G8ow?t=1369 but imho this can work because that vertex is shared by 4 coplanar faces... in blender you can do this, using (eg) local or normal coordinates... see also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93140/face-and-normal-constraint-when-moving-vertex-edge-like-3ds-max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is to scale selected vertices while locking normal Z axis.

To do so, enable *Normal* [transform orientation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or from viewport header. Select vertices, enable *Scale* tool with <kbd>S</kbd> and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to lock movement along global Z axis, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> once again to lock normal Z axis. After that move your mouse to change amount of effect.

[image: gif-of-trepanating-monkey]

It's also possible to move vertices as well while constraining normal Z axis making them roughly stay on the same surface.

Answer (score 0):

with the vertex selected, if you hit G key twice, it will slide across the edge that it's connected to

If you want to slide both edges towards each other, you may want to find a midpoint between the two vertices, select it, then place the 3D cursor on that midpoint using the snap cursor to selected (**shift + S**)

[image]

After that, change your pivot point to your 3d cursor, then scale the vertices, it will come closed to the 3D cursor as you scale.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I got what you say, and the op asks, this is not helping at all...